# How to use captcha in my HTML pop up window

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic, captcha

I want to use a captcha in my HTML pop up window, I found a simple captcha on the net but how do I write the if-statement to make sure the person can't press the agree button before he has solved the captcha? How do I refer to captcha asp file?

Part of my code I used in HTML:

```html
<div style="position:relative; width :100%; height:140px;" >
    <iframe id="captcha" class="ato" src="captcha/test.asp" style="position:relative; width:100%; height:140px;background: linear-gradient(to top, #F9DEB1 0%, #FFFFFF  70%);border-color: #ECD3C4; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid;border-radius:30px;"></iframe>    
</div>
```

Note: I checked the the `if`, but how do I refer to Boolean that is in asp file outside of my html file?

```
ן»¿<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT"%>
<%
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
Response.AddHeader "pragma","no-cache"
Response.Expires = -1
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function RefreshImage(valImageId) {
            var objImage = document.getElementById(valImageId)
            if (objImage == undefined) {
                return;
            }
            var now = new Date();
            objImage.src = objImage.src.split('?')[0] + '?x=' + now.toUTCString();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post">
    <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 20px;">
        <%
        if Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" and IsEmpty(Request.Form("btnRetry")) then
            Dim lblResult, lblColor
            if IsEmpty(Session("ASPCAPTCHA")) or Trim(Session("ASPCAPTCHA")) = "" then
                lblResult = "This test has expired."
                lblColor = "red"
            else
                Dim TestValue : TestValue = Trim(Request.Form("txtCaptcha"))
                '//Uppercase fix for turkish charset//
                TestValue = Replace(TestValue, "i", "I", 1, -1, 1)
                TestValue = Replace(TestValue, "ִ°", "I", 1, -1, 1)
                TestValue = Replace(TestValue, "ִ±", "I", 1, -1, 1)
                '////////////////////
                TestValue = UCase(TestValue)

                if StrComp(TestValue, Trim(Session("ASPCAPTCHA")), 1) = 0 then
                    lblResult = "CAPTCHA PASSED"
                    lblColor = "green"

                else
                    lblResult = "CAPTCHA FAILED"
                    lblColor = "red"
                end if
                '//IMPORTANT: You must remove session value for security after the CAPTCHA test//
                Session("ASPCAPTCHA") = vbNullString
                Session.Contents.Remove("ASPCAPTCHA")
                '////////////////////
            end if
        %>
        <p><span style="color: <%=lblColor%>; font-weight: bold;"><%=lblResult%></span></p>
        <input type="submit" name="btnRetry" id="btnRetry" value="Take another test" />
        <%else%>
        <img src="captcha.asp" id="imgCaptcha" />&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="RefreshImage('imgCaptcha');">Get a new challenge</a><br />
        Write the characters in the image above<br />
        <input type="text" name="txtCaptcha" id="txtCaptcha" value="" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
        <%end if%>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: CAPTCHA validation logic has to be implemented server-side, not client-side.

Comment: i would mind if you explain more and in this case i write the site from scratches so what do you mean?

Comment: Your server side is asp-classic or java.. ?

Comment: *"How do I refer to captcha **asp file**?"* hmmm what do you think @Freelex?

Comment: Just noted that "java" tag was there

Comment: i mean not  to the file but to a Boolean inside and if condition inside asp file. and do i have some way or by pass not to create server-side responce but to make from an  client-side response

Comment: @alien Like Halcyon said, the validation should be made on server-side, but if you want to access the value of a boolean inside a c# class you could use something like this `alert('<%= CSVariable %>');` and declare the CSVariable  `public`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution would be to use this [link](http://captcha.com/doc/asp/captcha-for-asp.html).

It provides a 3 steps solution

**1- Copy the files to your solution**

**2- Add the client-side code**

```
<!-- #include file ="BotDetect.asp" -->
</head>

[…]

<% ' Adding BotDetect Captcha to the page 
    Dim SampleCaptcha : Set SampleCaptcha = (New Captcha)("SampleCaptcha")
    SampleCaptcha.UserInputID = "CaptchaCode"
    Response.Write SampleCaptcha.Html
%>

<input name="CaptchaCode" id="CaptchaCode" type="text" />
```

**3- Add the server-side code**

```
<% If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" Then
    Dim isHuman : isHuman = SampleCaptcha.Validate()

    If Not isHuman Then 
        'show error message
    Else 
        'Captcha validation passed
    End If 
End If %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always used the APIs available from the reCaptcha project - they have great example code, and it saves me having to re-invent the wheel all the time!
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/

Comment: tried but how do i write the condition for capthca is solved or not?

Comment: There is extensive documentation on the site, you were asking about java, which is here: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/java but other language guides are also spelled out in detail.